# Shortcut to open just saved PDF in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, automation

I find myself often having to search for a PDF I just created to open it in Preview.  This waste of time is begging for automation, though can't figure out how to do this in Keyboard Maestro, for example.  Any ideas on how to automate this so that a keyboard trigger will open it?

Comment: If you just created the PDF why do you have to search for it. Don't you know where you put it?

Comment: What do you create the PDF with?

Comment: Its not that I don't know where I put it, it is the navigating to it that is a waste of time since the "start point" for the open PDF is not what was just saved...I am creating PDF with the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how you are creating them, you can create a Finder window with a smart search that shows files created within the last day, and then sort that window by creation date. The most recent file you've created will be on the top.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you describe the problem being the need to navigate to open the file. I think I understand what you mean: there's no history in the open-file dialog, so when you use "open file" in another application, the location it first presents is not where you saved the file. Consequently, you have to navigate around (within the open-file dialog) to where you *did* save the file. If that is indeed the problem, then I suggest looking at [Default Folder](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/).  I've been using it to solve this particular problem for many years and it has worked well for me.